# How to tune this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle-apps

I am calculating the resource cost:

```
        SELECT NVL(sum(WT.TRANSACTION_QUANTITY* WTA.RATE_OR_AMOUNT),0) 
        --    INTO l_resource_cost
        FROM APPS.WIP_TRANSACTION_ACCOUNTS WTA, APPS.WIP_TRANSACTIONS WT
        WHERE WTA.TRANSACTION_ID = WT.TRANSACTION_ID
        AND WTA.ORGANIZATION_ID = WT.ORGANIZATION_ID
        AND WTA.ACCOUNTING_LINE_TYPE =7
        AND WTA.WIP_ENTITY_ID = 1757957
        AND wt.operation_seq_num = 10;
```

The tables are Oracle ebs WIP tables, the data is correct but this is need to be executed for thousands of records.

How can I tune it?

can I attache the explain plan here?

Comment: 1000's of rows isn't that many. Any indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(WT.TRANSACTION_QUANTITY * WTA.RATE_OR_AMOUNT), 0) 
        --    INTO l_resource_cost
FROM APPS.WIP_TRANSACTION_ACCOUNTS WTA JOIN
     APPS.WIP_TRANSACTIONS WT
     ON WTA.TRANSACTION_ID = WT.TRANSACTION_ID AND
        WTA.ORGANIZATION_ID = WT.ORGANIZATION_ID
WHERE WTA.ACCOUNTING_LINE_TYPE = 7 AND WTA.WIP_ENTITY_ID = 1757957 AND
      wt.operation_seq_num = 10;
```

Indexes will help the query.  I would recommend:

- `APPS.WIP_TRANSACTION_ACCOUNTS(ACCOUNTING_LINE_TYPE, WIP_ENTITY_ID, RATE_OR_AMOUNT)`
- `APPS.WIP_TRANSACTIONS(TRANSACTION_ID, ORGANIZATION_ID, operation_seq_num, TRANSACTION_QUANTITY)`.

Comment: both type of sqls are tried, the only thing which your answer has, and done a majec including the columns (rate_or_amount and transaction_quantity) in indexes. thanks

Comment: I have another query, which is very lengthy. how can I share that query? can I attache that query to my question?